# Shared memory sync using semaphore

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory

I have two codes : **PRODUCER (PR)** and **CONSUMER (CO)**. There is a block of memory (Mat) (a 3D matrix to be precise) which needs to be shared between both the programs. I am currently using **shared memory** based IPC functions to share the memory space between the two codes.

Constraints:

1. **PR** is the owner of the `Mat` and performs iterations changing the values of the matrix. **CO** is the user of the `Mat` and only reads the values and uses for some further calculation
2. **PR** should write the data first and then should wait for the **CO** to read and use the values of the `Matrix` then signalling **PR** to proceed with further iteration and it should continue like this.

What I am currently using is -

**PRODUCER**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/ipc.h>
#include  <sys/shm.h>

#define  NOT_READY  -1
#define  FILLED     0
#define  TAKEN      1

#define  nx (400)
#define  ny (400)
#define  nz (400)

struct Memory {
     int      status;
     double   u_x[nx+1][ny+2][nz+2];
}

int 
main(int  argc, char *argv[])
{
     key_t          ShmKEY;
     int            ShmID;
     struct Memory  *ShmPTR;
     int            i, j, k;
     int            niter = 5;

     int            sumX[niter],sumY[niter],sumZ[niter];

     ShmKEY = ftok(".", 'x'); // getting the unique identifier key from directory location
     ShmID = shmget(ShmKEY, sizeof(struct Memory), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
     if (ShmID < 0) {
          printf("*** shmget error (server) ***\n");
          exit(1);
     }

     ShmPTR = (struct Memory *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);
     if ((int) ShmPTR == -1) {
          printf("*** shmat error (server) ***\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     printf("Server attached the memory to its virtual space...\n");

     ShmPTR->status  = NOT_READY; // setting the status to be not ready before filling it

     for (int m = 0; m < niter; m++){
        for (i=0; i<=nx; i++) for (j=0; j<=ny+1; j++) for (k=0; k<=nz+1; k++) 
           ShmPTR->u_x[i][j][k] = m; // filling the array with iteration number (just for depiction purpose)
        ShmPTR->status = FILLED; // change the status to Filled
        //printf("Please start the client in another window...\n");
        while (ShmPTR->status != TAKEN)
             sleep(1);
     }

     printf("Server has detected the completion of its child...\n");
     shmdt((void *) ShmPTR);
     printf("Server has detached its shared memory...\n");
     shmctl(ShmID, IPC_RMID, NULL);
     printf("Server has removed its shared memory...\n");
     printf("Server exits...\n");
     exit(0);
}
```

CONSUMER

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/ipc.h>
#include  <sys/shm.h>

#define  NOT_READY  -1
#define  FILLED     0
#define  TAKEN      1

#define  nx (400)
#define  ny (400)
#define  nz (400)

struct Memory {
    int      status;
    double   u_x[nx+1][ny+2][nz+2];
}

int
main(void)
{
    key_t          ShmKEY;
    int            ShmID;
    struct Memory  *ShmPTR;
    int            i, j, k;

    int            niter = 5;
    int            sumX[niter];

    ShmKEY = ftok(".", 'x');
    ShmID = shmget(ShmKEY, sizeof(struct Memory), 0666);
    if (ShmID < 0) {
          printf("*** shmget error (client) ***\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Client has received a shared memory...\n");

    ShmPTR = (struct Memory *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);
    if ((int) ShmPTR == -1) {
        printf("*** shmat error (client) ***\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Client has attached the shared memory to it's virtual memory space...\n");

    for (int m =0; m<niter; m++){
        sumX[m] = 0;
        while (ShmPTR->status != FILLED)
            ;
        printf("Client found the data is ready, performing sanity check...\n");
        // read the integers and check for the sum

        for (i=0; i<=nx; i++) for (j=0; j<=ny+1; j++) for (k=0; k<=nz+1; k++) 
            sumX[m] +=  ShmPTR->u_x[i][j][k];
        printf("Cycle %d : sumX-> %d\n", m,sumX[m);

        ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;
        printf("Client has informed server data have been taken...\n");
    }
    shmdt((void *) ShmPTR);
    printf("Client has detached its shared memory...\n");
    printf("Client exits...\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

What I am doing right now is using a member of the struct called `status` to kind of prevent race conditions. From what I have read till now, **semaphores** allow a similar thing in IPC.

Question: How to use semaphore in this such that the memory space which needs to be shared is just the array(s) and not wrapping it in a struct with a self defined flag ?

Edit1: Or maybe `mutex` for that matter if it is better than semaphore for this application.

Edit2: Following @Stargateur answer which works for this code but in the production code where `nx`, `ny` and `nz` are variables, how does one define a *shared memory* for the struct consisting of a member which is a *variable length multidimensional array* ? ( ofcourse it would live until the call `shmdt` and `shmctl` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will advice you to implement your feature with two semaphores, one for unlock produser, one for unlock consumer.

> How to use semaphore in this such that the memory space which needs to be shared is just the array(s) and not wrapping it in a struct with a self defined flag ?

Yes but why separate the data and the semaphore associate with the data ?

I would do the following:

```
struct Memory {
     sem_t    prod;
     sem_t    cons;
     double   u_x[nx+1][ny+2][nz+2];
};

// produser
sem_init(&ShmPTR->cons, !0, 0);
sem_init(&ShmPTR->prod, !0, 1);

 for (int m = 0; m < niter; m++) {
     sem_wait(&ShmPTR->prod);
     // ...
     sem_post(&ShmPTR->cons);
 }

// consumer
for (int m =0; m<niter; m++) {
     sem_wait(&ShmPTR->cons);
     // ...
     sem_post(&ShmPTR->prod);
}
```

> Or maybe mutex for that matter if it is better than semaphore for this
>   application.

mutex can't be share between process.

By the way, you use an `int` to iterate on a array, you should use `size_t`

Comment: bit struggling with the clubbing the semaphore and the data ( there are more such arrays, i have just showed one such array u_x there exists u_y and u_z ). is there a particular place where you can refer me to , to understand a bit more about semaphore.

Comment: @datapanda Well, I'm don't know if there are such resource. My method is to read the documentation, this is generally enough for me, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html, when you finish to understand the mechanics the only limit is your imagination. If you need a more detailed answer you can update or create a new question.

Comment: This did worked out seamlessly in the example code, let me give it a try on the production code. On a side note, why do I have to link pthread library while compiling the program with semaphores in it (semaphore.h)

Comment: @datapanda History reason, "Programs using the POSIX semaphores API must be compiled with cc -pthread to link against the real-time library, librt.", not very important but it's needed.

Comment: and hope they are portable on HPC clusters running Linux which are indeed POSIX compliant. Thanks @Stargateur

Comment: your answer worked for the code listed here but in the production code nx, ny and nz are variables so any inputs on how to define a shared memory for the struct with a member being a multidimensional array ?

Comment: @datapanda Of course, you can use FAM, note that it's feature of C for experimented user, http://rextester.com/ISEPNM55786. I used `malloc()` but you can just replace by `shmget()` but you get the idea.

Comment: I came across an example in the openmpi library with the shared memory initialisation being done with `shmem_init()` freeing done with `shmem_free()` and finalize call with `shmem_finalize`. The header that contains the call is `shmem.h` which is the different than from what I am using `shm.h` and thus the calls are different. Is there any fundamental reason of choosing one over the other ?

Comment: @datapanda I don't know maybe this worst a question, if you do be sure to ask about technical difference and not opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to keep **PR** and **CO** as separate processes, you can try to fork one of the processes from the other to synchronize them. In this particular case, my suggestion is to fork **CO** from **PR** process. Here is briefly my idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char *name="SHARED";
    const int SIZE = 4096;


    pid_t pidA;
    pidA = fork();

    if (pidA < 0)
    {
        printf("forkA Failed" );
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pidA == 0) // Child process A
    {


        // Read from the shared memory object.


        exit(0);
    }
    else // Parent process
    {

        int shm_fd;
        /* pointer to shared memory obect */
        void* ptr;
        /* create the shared memory object */
        shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
        /* configure the size of the shared memory object */
        ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
        /* memory map the shared memory object */
        ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);



        /* write to the shared memory object */



        // Wait for child to read matrix
        wait(NULL);


        printf("Program finished------\n");
    }
}
```

But we all know that threads are more **lightweight**, hence **preferable**. You can use semaphore with two threads as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t can_read,can_write; // declare two global semaphore

void* threadPR(void* arg)
{
  while(true)
  {
    //wait
    sem_wait(&can_write);


    //Write to matrix


    //signal
    sem_post(&can_read);
  }
}

void* threadCO(void* arg)
{
  while(true)
  {
    //wait
    sem_wait(&can_read);


    //Read the matrix


    //signal
    sem_post(&can_write);
  }
}


int main()
{
    // initialize the semaphore
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    // declare two threads
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,threadPR,NULL); // Run the PR thread

    // do whatever needed before running CO

    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,threadCO,NULL); // Run the CO thread

    // wait for threads to join
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);

    // free the semaphore
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

You can add required initializations as globals to this implementation.

Comment: In my case the intended use case will not allow me to fork as there are two separate codes one which is openMP parallelised and the other one is an MPI parallelised code. MPI code needs read access to a memory block which is created and modified by openMP code in each iteration. :(

Comment: You need a shared common storage for your both openMP and MPI parallelised programs then. Or you can change one of the program if it is okay for you. Or you can force same context for both program, which i do not suggest at all for parallelised programs, it will bring huge overhead.

Comment: the problem is the OpenMP code is a legacy code which is very difficult to port to MPI in a straightforward manner and the MPI code heavily depends on an opensource library which needs MPI to run by default. So I am a bit stuck in an odd situation leaving the block of memory that I need in my MPI code to be shared by the OpenMP code.

Comment: I see. If i were you, I would use a shared file system and handle the synchronization on the file system level.

Comment: Could you elaborate on it ? (Maybe it will help me in deciding the course of solution ) I presume a filesystem would lead to disk IO. To give you more context both of the codes in the discussion are CFD codes where I am interested in sharing the velocity matrices which are huge ones.

Comment: Are you running both programs on a multi-core cluster?

Comment: Well lets talk about the scenario ( not the best case ) which I am currently exploring. With shared memory thing that I am implementing I am limited to only one node of the cluster ( the openMP code is anyways limited to one node, but my MPI code can indeed use many more cores/nodes in a cluster ). I am presuming that you are pointing towards a solution that would let me do away with this bottleneck. if so, I am indeed waiting for your pointers. I am not that much of "computer science" guy so your help would matter a lot.

Comment: Any background always welcome :) Since it seems impossible to change to current structure of your **PR** and **CO** programs, you can use a file for reading/writing your matrix. But if there is no parallel file system that can be reached from your cluster, overhead will be huge. Finally, you can check openMP and MPI related C libraries if there is a cross-context shared object type or a monitor interface for both OpenMP and MPI.